# How to use htaccess to make root and /index.php display as /news?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My news page can be reached on these urls: `www.domain.com/index.php` and `www.domain.com/` (both exactly the same page).

I want to make these urls a little prettier, so I want them both to redirect to `www.domain.com/news`.

So:

1. I want to use htaccess to make sure that people who type: `www.domain.com/news` in the address bar, see the contents of `www.domain.com/index.php`.
2. I want to use htaccess to redirect everyone from the ugly urls (when they try to access them directly) to the pretty one, so people who type: `www.domain.com/index.php` or `www.domain.com/` get redirected to `www.domain.com/news`

Of course this has a potential for looping, so how do I do this properly?

---

background information: these are the rules I've already got in place (and I'm using modx as a cms):

```
#########################
# Turn on URL rewriting #
#########################

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


#####################################
# Convert caps to lowercase letters #
#####################################

# If there are caps, set HASCAPS to true and skip next rule
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]

# Skip this entire section if no uppercase letters in requested URL
RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=28]

# Replace single occurance of CAP with cap, then process next Rule.
RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2
RewriteRule ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ $1b$2
RewriteRule ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ $1c$2
RewriteRule ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ $1d$2
RewriteRule ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ $1e$2
RewriteRule ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ $1f$2
RewriteRule ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ $1g$2
RewriteRule ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ $1h$2
RewriteRule ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ $1i$2
RewriteRule ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ $1j$2
RewriteRule ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ $1k$2
RewriteRule ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ $1l$2
RewriteRule ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ $1m$2
RewriteRule ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ $1n$2
RewriteRule ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ $1o$2
RewriteRule ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ $1p$2
RewriteRule ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2
RewriteRule ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ $1r$2
RewriteRule ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ $1s$2
RewriteRule ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ $1t$2
RewriteRule ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ $1u$2
RewriteRule ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ $1v$2
RewriteRule ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ $1w$2
RewriteRule ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ $1x$2
RewriteRule ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2
RewriteRule ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2

# If there are any uppercase letters, restart at very first RewriteRule in file.
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]


######################################
# Convert domain to prefixed version #
######################################

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]


##############################################################
# Redirect .html requests to equivalent pages without suffix #
##############################################################

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301,L]


##########################
# The Friendly URLs part #
##########################

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA,NC]


##########################################
# Serve .htc files with proper MIME type #
##########################################

# Critical for XP SP2 (use if your host allows htaccess MIME type overrides).
AddType text/x-component .htc


#######################
# Turn compression on #
#######################

php_flag zlib.output_compression On
php_value zlib.output_compression_level 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this code after RewriteBase line:

```
# external redirect from /index.php to /news
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(index\.php)?[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /news [R=301,L]

# internal forward from  /news to /index.php
RewriteRule ^news/?$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to make the root of the site: `domain.com` point to `domain.com/news` as well? Because `domain.com` and `domain.com/index.php` have exactly the same content, and it would be better for seo to make both of them point to `domain.com/news`.

Comment: I updated my question to reflect my previous comment, hope you can help me out!

Comment: Alright, edited my answer based on your comment. Please try again.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you so much! If I could give 20 upvotes I would :).

Answer (score 0):

You can insert this simple rule:

```
Redirect /index.php http://www.domain.com/news.php
DirectoryIndex news.php
```

Comment: I tried it, but I get a 403 - Forbidden error. And if I try only the first rule, it goes into a loop, the url ends up looking like this: http://www.domain.com/news?q=news&q=news&q=news (etc.). Must be some sort of interaction between modx and htaccess, but I don't understand it..

Comment: And if I just try `Redirect http://www.domain.com/index.php http://www.domain.com/news`, and type domain.com, it just stays at domain.com and doesn't change the url to domain.com/news..

Comment: Well could be a variety of things.
Can you give more information on you directory structure?

Comment: Well it's a cms, so there is no real directory structure I think. The pages are generated from the database. Generally they look like: `www.domain.com/index.php?id=123`, and are rewritten to their alias (so domain.com/news, domain.com/about, etc.). And part of that is done in the cms itself (modx). Only the removal of the `index.php?id=` is done in htaccess I think..

Comment: Well this was very important thing to say. Forget the rules above. You must handle the situation in your CMS.

Comment: But rewrites/redirects with htaccess are still effective right? Because doing this with the cms would require me messing with the source code, and that's not really easy. I just want to do a simple redirect (or a rewrite, don't know which one I need), should that not be possible?

Comment: Couldn't I just do a 301 rewrite instead of a redirect? Thus only rewriting index.php as news?

Comment: Also, the infinite loop might be because of conflicting htaccess rules, but I don't know which ones..

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a specific rule.

Something like this in your case in the .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^news/?$ index.php [R=301,NC,L]
```

I have not checked this.

Comment: I've tried it, but it doesn't change the url when I try to access domain.com/index.php, the url stays the same and isn't rewritten. I've rephrased my question, maybe that helps.

Comment: Did you include the [R=310] part? It tells the browser to change the url in the address bar

Comment: You basically have to redirect / to /index.php and rewrite /index.php as /news, the first task is done by the server itself, and the rule does the second task.

Comment: I copied your suggestion exactly, but it doesn't work. Any idea why? Does it matter where in the htaccess file I put the rule, or is it maybe in conflict with the other rules?

Comment: I restarted my browser to see if it was cached older 301 redirects, but that wasn't it either.

Comment: You can generally put it anywhere after "RewriteEngine On"
I am also surprised this isnt working. It should by all means. I cant see it conflicting it with any rules in your htaccess.
Try adding Options -Indexes and Options +FollowSymLinks if your site doesnt use /index.php at every link. Erase my rule and see if your index page doesnt open at the webroot now.

Comment: The weird thing is that after a refresh, when I type domain.com/news, it changes the url to domain.com/index.php. So it's sort of working the other way around now..

Comment: It does work when I type domain.com/news though, if I do that the url remains domain.com/news, but I see the contents of domain.com/index.php. The only thing that's not working is that when you type domain.com, you aren't taken to domain.com/news and the url stays at domain.com..

Comment: Btw. I tried your last suggestion (options -indexes and options +followsymlinks), but again the only thing that changes is that when I type domain.com/news the url is changed to domain.com/index.php. If you try to access domain.com, the url stays at domain.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your site start to be any page you wish. I'd just go to System Settings, make /news/ the homepage and you should be all set.